# How to get special dates?

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x

I am trying to get value of special `$date_start` and `$date_end` on product page. I'm using opencart version 2.0x. please help manually thank you.

Comment: what makes a date "special"?

Comment: This is related to products special price `date start` and `date end` ?

Comment: yes this is related to products special price @zedBlackbeard

Comment: @protik : frontend or admin. ?

Comment: in front of `product.tpl`

Comment: @protik : are you using your own theme ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Special price date

create you own `ocmod file` for ex. `special_price.ocmod.xml`, Paste the following code and install from `extension installer`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name><![CDATA[<font color="#0000"><b>Special Price</font>]]></name>
    <version><![CDATA[<b>1.0</b>]]></version>
    <code>specialprice_dates</code>
    <author><![CDATA[<font color="#CC0000"><b>A2bizz Blogs</b></font>]]></author>
    <link><![CDATA[http://blogs.a2bizz.com]]></link>


    <file path="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[ $data['discounts'] = array(); ]]></search>
            <add position="before" ><![CDATA[
              if($data['special']){ 
                $special_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getSpecialPriceInfo($this->request->get['product_id']);
                }else{
                $special_info = '';
                }

            ]]></add>
        </operation>
         <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[ 'special'     => $special, ]]></search>
            <add position="after" ><![CDATA[
             'special_info'     => $special_info,  
            ]]></add>
        </operation> 
    </file> 

    <file path="catalog/model/catalog/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search><![CDATA[ public function getLatestProducts($limit) { ]]></search>
             <add position="before" ><![CDATA[
                public function getSpecialPriceInfo($product_id){ 
            $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special WHERE product_id = '".$product_id."'"); 
            return $sql->row;
        } 
                 ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

 </modification>
```

Add following code in product.tpl

```
<?php if ($product['special_info']) { ?>
   <p><?php echo "<pre>"; print_r($product['special_info']); exit;?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

Here you can get the special price information.

Comment: No want the date_start and date_end value of special price to add a countdown. I don't want module. @zed